# removing a temp table in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, temp-tables

I am having problems removing a temp table in SQL server.

I have a stored procedure but when I run in via my application it says:

> "There is already an object named '#WeekList' in the database"

when i try to drop the table i get the following message:

> Cannot drop the table '#WeekList', because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission.

My SP is as follows:

```
USE [test_staff]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_create_week_list]    Script Date: 03/20/2012 09:35:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_create_week_list]

AS

CREATE TABLE #WeekList
    (
    month_date date
    )


DECLARE @REPORT_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_BEGINING VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @REPORT_DATE = '2011-01-19T00:00:00'
--SELECT @REPORT_DATE = GETDATE() -- should grab the date now.
SELECT @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'MONDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 1
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'TUESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 2
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'WEDNESDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 3
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'THURSDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 4
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'FRIDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 5
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SATURDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 6
ELSE IF @WEEK_BEGINING = 'SUNDAY'
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @WEEK_START_DATE DATETIME, @WEEK_END_DATE DATETIME
--GET THE WEEK START DATE
SELECT @WEEK_START_DATE = @REPORT_DATE - (DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE) - 1)
--GET THE WEEK END DATE
SELECT @WEEK_END_DATE = @REPORT_DATE + (7 - DATEPART(DW, @REPORT_DATE))
PRINT 'Week Start: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_START_DATE)
PRINT 'Week End: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @WEEK_END_DATE)

DECLARE @Interval int = datediff(WEEK,getdate(),@WEEK_START_DATE)+1

SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE
, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE
INTO #WeekList

WHILE @Interval <= 0
    BEGIN
    set @WEEK_START_DATE=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@WEEK_START_DATE)
    set @WEEK_END_DATE=DATEADD(WEEK,1,@WEEK_END_DATE)
    INSERT INTO #WeekList values (@WEEK_START_DATE,@WEEK_END_DATE)
    SET @Interval += 1;
    END

SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), Start_Week, 106) AS 'Start',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), End_Week, 106) AS 'End',
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start_Week) / 7 AS week_ref   -- create the unique week reference number

FROM #WeekList
ORDER BY Start_Week DESC

DROP TABLE #WeekList
```

Comment: I surgest you try to rewrite that stored procedure. I see alot of dead code and a terrible way of looping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the SP there is a problem in following statement.

```
SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE
, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE
INTO #WeekList
```

Instead of that try this one, it may work.

```
INSERT INTO #WeekList
SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE
, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE
```

Comment: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Any ideas?

Comment: there is problem in declare table statement.  you need to add two column as define below. it will work fine.                                                                                                                                CREATE TABLE #WeekList
    (
    Start_Week date,
    End_Week date
    )

Comment: +1 Explanation of "the problem": `select ... into` tries to create a table, but there is already a `create table` at the top of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

You can drop the `#YourTable` temporary table using this code:

```
if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#YourTable%')
    drop table #YourTable
```

Best place to do this is right before you run `insert into` to create the table.

Comment: Pleas dont use this exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#YourTable%')
use insteed 
if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.sys.#YourTable') IS NOT NULL)

Answer (score 2):

In the middle of the code you have:

```
select ...  
into #WeekList
```

This will try to create a new temporary table called #WeekList which you'd already created using the CREATE TABLE statement at the top of the proc

If you change the insert to the style

```
insert into #WeekList (columns)  
select ...
```

Then you will get rid of the error

Comment: Sorry didnt quite get that? did you mean: SELECT Start_Week=@WEEK_START_DATE
, End_Week=@WEEK_END_DATE
INTO #WeekList

Comment: Yes. That statement will try to create a new table called #WeekList. Also note your original #WeekList table definition has a single column whereas you're using it subsequently expecting two columns

Answer (score 2):

--Check if it exists

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
drop table #temptable
END
```

and while using temporary table insert, specify column names externally
like

```
insert into #temptable(col1,col2..) values(1,2,..)
```

Comment: @SOLDIER-OF-FORTUNE - Corrected the script. This should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use table variable inplace of the #Temp table it's more better option.
If you want to use #temp table then check for the existance of the #temp table in the Tempdb database then you are able to get that #temp table exist or not.

Comment: _"it's more better option"_ Would you care to explain?

Comment: I have also created a physical table in the DB. [dbo].[WeekList] and still get the same problem. Only difference is i can drop the table.

Comment: A table variable is created in memory, and so performs slightly better than #temp tables (also because there is even less locking and logging in a table variable), Table variables are automatically cleared when the procedure or function goes out of scope, so you don't have to remember to drop or clear the data

Comment: Kuldip can you provide us with an example?

Comment: @sp-1986 i don't see any other problem in your code if drop will give you error then check in tempdb that #temp table exist or not then you can run your drop command.

Comment: for help - http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see that could hint at what's wrong there is the lack of BEGIN and END?  I use this all the time, but I always put BEGIN and END around the sprocs code...

Answer (score 1):

To check if a temp table exists:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#yourTempTableName') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #yourTempTableName;
```

Note as mentioned in the other answers you have created a temp table #WeekList with only one column, you then try to re-create the temp table using the short-hand `SELECT ... INTO #Weeklist`; which in your case you are selecting two columns, this is where the issue is occurring. I would remove the `CREATE TABLE` statement at the beginning of your code and just use the `SELECT ... INTO` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that a temporary table with the same name is being created two times in the same batch. First by CREATE TABLE statement and second by SELECT .. INTO statement
As per Microsoft BOL, "If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names."

This is a feature by design as per the clarification on the Microsoft Connect Bug ID 666430.

Please see the link [temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created](http://www.tectalks.com/493/temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created/) for further information